# Adding a value to elements in columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data.frame:

```
df<-structure(list(Ns.infection = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 18, 
    27, 45, 75, 92, 101, 115, 4, 10, 13, 20, 21, 24, 28, 34, 42, 
    45), Bs.infection = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 10, 4, 13, 25, 43, 71, 97, 
    124, 151, 183, 203, 14, 20, 26, 40, 48, 56, 67, 75, 83, 92), 
        Es.infection = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 13, 21, 31, 41, 
        54, 69, 80, 93, 4, 6, 8, 9, 15, 18, 23, 24, 26, 29), totinfectionscenario = c(0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 8, 20, 44, 82, 129, 183, 253, 312, 364, 411,22, 36, 47, 69, 84, 98, 118, 133, 151, 166), t = 0:25), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I need to add the value in row 6 in each column to the elements in the same column that are in rows 7:16. For instance, column totinfectionscenario should look (after adding 12 in totinfectionscenario[6]:

```
totinfectionscenario = c(0, 
        0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 20, 32, 56, 94, 141, 195, 265, 324, 376, 423, 
        22, 36, 47, 69, 84, 98, 118, 133, 151, 166)
```

I need to make this a function as I have to do it with a list of dataframes. dplyr versions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? please share your code.

Comment: Probably easier to do in base R: `df[7:13, 1:4] + df[6, 1:4][rep(1,7),]`

Comment: thanks for your answer @jaap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res   <- df
res[] <- lapply(res, function(x) {x[7:16] <- x[7:16] + x[6]; return(x)})
```

In your example you add `element 6` to `elements 7:16`.

Since you want to do it for "each column" I do it for each column using `lapply`.

---

You can of course use `df` directly and no `res` is needed.

---

If you have a list of dataframes. You can do the following:

```
listOfDataFrames <- list(df,df,df)

listOfDataFrames2 <- lapply(listOfDataFrames, function(DF){ DF[] <- lapply(DF, function(x) {x[7:16] <- x[7:16] + x[6]; return(x)}); return(DF)})
```

Comment: this seems to work as intended. There is something I do not get. I have been trying `x[7:16] <- x[7:16] + x[6]` without the lapply and always get _Error: Column indexes must be at most 5 if positive, not 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16_  why (I am bit new to R).

Comment: same if I want to restrict the number of columns in your answer to x[7:16, 1:4] I get incorrect number of dimensions. I am a bit confused with this (not your answer, but the errors that R provides)

Comment: Inside `lapply` the `x` is a vector. So this code is intended to run on the individual columns. If you don't want to use lapply, you can use Jaap's way. Make sure you `rep` the right amount of rows.

Comment: I understand. the problem with your method is that data frames lose their structure if I use it with lapply in a list  (I have a list of 500 data frames with these 5 variables structure). I've been trying to figure this out for hours. is there a way I can keep the structure. thanks in advance.

Comment: thats why I had the `res` variable. You want to insert it back into the old structure to keep the structure.

Comment: Thank you very much @Andre Elrico. I have spent half a day (I really mean it) trying to figure out how to do this. I learnt something new with this thing of keeping the structure. thanks